# Data Fetching from an Aave subgraph

Tags: hardhat, defi, aave, the-graph

Hi guys I am writing a dApp which deals with liquidations flash loans etc,

The 1st step of development is to receive the user addresses who have borrowed more than zero from 'The Graph'

I use hardhat.js (also I can with to hardhat.ts if necessary), the steps I've taken when setting up the repo :

1. file new file in vs code + I've already have git and node installed
2. `npx hardhat` or  `yarn add --dev hardhat`
3. if I use yarn then I run `hardhat` and create a javascript project
4. I install  `@apollo/client` , `react` , `react-dom`, `apollo-link-http` to interact with 'The Graph'

here is my script for fetching data:

```js
const {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  createHttpLink,
  gql,
} = require("@apollo/client");

const subgraphEndpoint =
  "https://gateway.thegraph.com/api/[api-key]/subgraphs/id/HB1Z2EAw4rtPRYVb2Nz8QGFLHCpym6ByBX6vbCViuE9F"; // Replace with the actual Aave subgraph endpoint

async function fetchDataFromGraph() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createHttpLink({ uri: subgraphEndpoint }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const query = gql`
    query {
      accounts(where: { borrows: { amount_gt: "0" } }) {
        id
        borrows(where: { amount_gt: "0" }) {
          id
          amount
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  try {
    const result = await client.query({
      query: query,
    });

    console.log(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }
}

fetchDataFromGraph();
```

For some reasons it doesn't works, maybe someone already tried integrating dApps with data from Aave,maybe someone knows how to fetch the data from 'The Graph' a more correct way, cause the way I choose provides me with tons of errors.